# Read data of type 'instance' in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gmail

I am using [this](https://github.com/charlierguo/gmail) library to read gmail inbox in python. This is the response I'm getting per mail :

```
From nobody Mon Dec 26 16:42:46 2016
Delivered-To: someone@examplemail.com
Received: by 10.28.211.66 with SMTP id ferf98er9fef9fr;
.
.
.
X-Source-Dir: erferfefefrref:/public_html
X-CMAE-Envelope: grtgrtgrtgrtgrt......

This is the message body
```

On checking the object type of the response, it returns `<type 'instance'>`

I am able to read properties like `Subject, Delivered-To, Received, X-Source-Dir` using this code

```
print response['subject']
print response['delivered-to']
```

But cannot read the message body ( `This is the message body` in the given example )

The documentation of the library says we can get the body using

```
print response.body
```

But that doesn't seem to work, and gives this error instead :

> Message instance has no attribute 'body'

Is there any other way I can extract the body from a data like above ??

Comment: open source code of this library and check - maybe it has different name or use function like `get_body()` .

Comment: BTW: you can also check `print dir(response)` to see methods in this object.

Comment: Thanks @furas thanks :) that helped, found a function to do the same !!!

Comment: Oh, excellent! Could you update your answer to include the solution you found? I'm curious and may want to play with this library. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the page you linked in your question:

```
unread = g.inbox().mail(unread=True)
print unread[0].body
# None

unread[0].fetch()
print unread[0].body
```

Is this not working for you?

Comment: It looks like it hasn't been updated in 3 years. It may be worth looking for a more recent option.

Comment: As @furas mentioned above, try looking at the methods of the object. Good luck!